# SSIS Import CSV delimited with quotes

Tags: ssis

Please help with import using SSIS (flat file to SQL)
Issue is that site column has a double quote due to a comma in the site name in my CSV file.

Well_ID,Site,Date,METER,GL,Gas,Oil,Water,Casing,Tubing,Choke,Notes

203032.01,"GARDNER, EL AL #2H",09/23/2017,0,0,0,0,0,,,,

203032.01,"GARDNER, EL AL #2H",09/24/2017,0,0,0,0,0,,,,

203032.01,"GARDNER, EL AL #2H",09/25/2017,0,0,0,0,0,,,,

203078.01,HAWN DICKSON #1H,09/23/2017,0,0,0,0,0,,,,

203078.01,HAWN DICKSON #1H,09/28/2017,0,0,0,0,0,,,,

203409.01,PORCUPINE #1H,09/28/2017,0,0,0,0,0,,,,

203411.01,BADGER #1H,09/23/2017,0,0,0,0,0,,,,

So my site name is for "GARDNER, EL AL #2H" is split between column site and Date thus my data is importing incorrectly to SQL table

Can someone please help me this SSIS question ?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the connection manager, set the Text qualifier to double quotes. This is on the General tab -> Text qualifier.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much I've been fighting this for an hour!  I looked at that but added 2 single quotes which didn't work.